# Property 'shadowRoot' does not exist on type <T> ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to use ShadowDOM within an Abstract Class of a Generic Type? I'm working on a few custom web components and decided to try to reduce the amount of DOM-related duplicate code.

Currently, my components extend 'HTMLElement'. However, I would like to have my components reference a base class like below  but I receive an error *'Property 'shadowRoot' does not exist on type 'B'.ts(2339)'*

```
abstract class B <T extends HTMLElement> {
    element: T;

    constructor(DOM:JSDOM, componentType:string) {
        this.element = <T>DOM.createElement(componentType);
        
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this.shadowRoot!.appendChild(this.element);
        
    }

    async connectedCallback() {
        this.appendChild(this.element);
    }

}
```

Comment: What should `T` represent, and where does `shadowRoot` come from?

Comment: shadowRoot is a property of Element.shadowRoot. <T> would represent any subclass type of HTMLElement such as HTMLDivElement.

Comment: Then it's `class B <T extends HTMLElement> extends Element {`

Comment: omg! that was the problem! T extends HTMLElement is the constraint of T but then I forgot to keep the B extends Element. Thank you!